# Lower bound for the $C^*$-unitisation norm?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra without unit. Its unitisation $A^+$ carries the $C^*$-norm

$$\|(a,\lambda)\|_{A^+} = \sup \{\|ax+\lambda x\|_A \;\big|\; \|x\|_A = 1 \},$$

which is the operator norm of $L_a + \lambda\,\text{id}_A$ in $\mathscr{L}(A)$, with $L_a$ denoting left multiplication by $a$.

> **My question**
>   Does a there exist an $A$ without unit together with concrete $a\in A$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ satisfying
>   $$\|(a,\lambda)\|_{A^+}\: < \:|\lambda |\; ?$$

If there's no such example, then let's put it the other way round: 
Can one prove that the lower bound
$$ |\lambda| \le \|(a,\lambda)\|_{A^+}$$
holds true $\forall\,(a,\lambda)\in A^+\:$?

If that is the case the title I chose for my question ought to be rectified to
"Trivial lower bound for the $C^*$-unitisation norm" I guess ...

Possibly, this latter estimate may be deduced from the canonical short exact sequence
$$A\hookrightarrow A^+\twoheadrightarrow\mathbb{C}$$
of $C^*$-algebras $\,-\,$ *but that's not clear to me*.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood the question, there is no such example: $|\lambda|\leq\|(a,\lambda)\|$ holds because the map $A^+\to\mathbb{C}$ is a $*$-homomorphism, and every $*$-homomorphism is norm-nonincreasing.

Comment: Doesn't this also follow from Hahn-Banach and the fact that in any unital algebra we assume the identity element has norm $1$?

Comment: @TobiasFritz  Thank you, you did not misunderstand it:  Your concise reply settles my question.  

Would (or could) one denote the *-hom $A^+\twoheadrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ as an _augmentation_ homomorphism?  

As I found in the meantime, there's the similar but extensive [post](http://mathoverflow.net/q/196141/89757).